# PIXI.js mask not being applied on sprite

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

I set up a sprite with no texture loaded, with just a filter applied which gives a gradient like this:

[image]

I am trying to apply this sprite to an image as a mask, however nothing is happening.
This is my code:

```js
const gradientFilter = generateGradientTexture(cellImage.gradient, renderer);
const gradient = new PIXI.Sprite();
gradient.width = renderer.width;
gradient.height = renderer.height;
gradient.filters = [gradientFilter];
applyImageProperties(gradient, cellImage, renderer);
Object.assign(gradient, {
  id: cellImage.objectId,
  isMask: Number(cellImage.isMaskingLayer) === 1,
});
if (index > 0 && Number(cellImage.isMaskingLayer) === 1) {
  const previousObject = objects.find(
    (o) => o.id === animation.images.reverse()[index - 1].objectId
  );
  previousObject.mask = gradient;
}
stage.addChild(gradient);
objects.push(gradient);
```

Can anyone direct on how to use this sprite on on image as an alpha mask? Could be that it does not work because there is no texture just a filter.

Comment: Please check this question and answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63946807/how-to-apply-mask-in-pixijs-container-that-will-not-show-its-color-at-page-refr/64093545#64093545 -  please try not adding mask to container (`stage`) as suggested there.

Comment: Possible to get more details? What does `generateGradientTexture` return? Are you running the supplied code in some sort of loop/function? I'm not sure if `objects` and `previousObject` could be creating the issue.